# How to receive request at the middle of a sequence in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

My requirement is like below,
[image]

1. Client initiate call to esb.
2. ESB creates a payload using payload factory mediator and calls another backend using call mediator.
3. Backend responds as a json response contains text as SUCCESS.
4. After SUCCESS response, same backend make a immediate request to a api in ESB with a json payload.
5. ESB sends 200 ok response.
6. ESB responds to client with json payload received in step 4.

So between step 1 to 6, client should be blocked. How can I achieve this goal.

NOTE: My ESB version is ESB 5.0.0

Comment: How are you trying to achieve the logic in the backend side? How will the backend know when to call the ESB?

Comment: In step 2, ESB sends some set of data that needs to be processed in backend. Since that backend process takes some time, it will respond with acknowledgement (step 3). After process completed, backend calls ESB with processed data (step 4). So as the answer for your question, "How will the backend know when to call the ESB?". Backend will call ESB whenever the data process is completed. NOTE: maximum time that backend process will take will be less than 10 seconds.